# AttributeError: module 'calc.views' has no attribute 'home'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I know there are some questions asked already but none of worked for me
server is not running  with the command throwing this error

calc urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home')
]
```

calc views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World !")
```

saish urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: That code looks ok. Make sure you have saved all your files and restarted the server. If that doesn't work, show the layout of your files in your project, and the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair  yeah bro I was just running inside the visual studio I thought files was autosave..thanks !! now it's working :-)